# Monte Carlo integration returning incorrect values, problem overwriting memory

Tags: c, montecarlo

I'm having trouble calculating integrals for the centre of mass of a torus, which should return (2.4076, 0.16210, 0.0).

The program works for an estimation of pi/4 however I think there is an issue when I try to overwrite existing points using the setRandomDomain() function.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DIM 1000000

double random_double() {
    static const int a = 16807;
    static const int c = 0;
    static const long long m = 2147483647;
    static long long seed = 1;
    seed = (a * seed + c) % m;
    return ((double) seed) / m;
}

typedef struct Domain_t {
    double *x;
    double *y;
    double *z;
} Domain;

void constructDomain(Domain (**p_domain)) {
    *p_domain = malloc(sizeof(Domain));
    if(p_domain == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Memory allocation failed\n");
    }
    (*p_domain)->x = malloc(DIM * sizeof(double));
    if ((*p_domain)->x == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Memory allocation failed\n");
    }
    (*p_domain)->y = malloc(DIM * sizeof(double));
    if ((*p_domain)->y == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Memory allocation failed\n");
    }
    (*p_domain)->z = malloc(DIM * sizeof(double));
    if((*p_domain)->z == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Memory allocation failed\n");
    }
}

void delDomain (Domain (**p_domain)) {
    if (p_domain != NULL) {
        free ((*p_domain)->z);
        free ((*p_domain)->y);
        free ((*p_domain)->x);
        free (*p_domain);
    }
}

double radiusFunc(double point_x, double point_y) {
    return sqrt(pow(point_x,2)+pow(point_y,2));
}

double G(double point_x, double point_y, double point_z, int R) {
    return pow(point_z,2)+pow(radiusFunc(point_x,point_y)-(double)R,2);
}

typedef struct Volume_t {
    int R;
    int r;
    int lower_x;
    int upper_x;
    int lower_y;
    int upper_y;
    int lower_z;
    int upper_z;
    int V;
} Volume;

void setVolume(Volume (*p_volume), int R, int r, int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2, int z1, int z2) {
    p_volume->R = R;
    p_volume->r = r;
    p_volume->lower_x = x1;
    p_volume->upper_x = x2;
    p_volume->lower_y = y1;
    p_volume->upper_y = y2;
    p_volume->lower_z = z1;
    p_volume->upper_z = z2;
    if(z1 == 0 && z2 == 0)
        p_volume->V = (x2-x1)*(y2-y1);
    else if(y1 == 0 && y2 == 0)
        p_volume->V = (x2-x1)*(z2-z1);
    else if(x1 == 0 && x2 == 0)
        p_volume->V = (y2-y1)*(z2-z1);
    else
        p_volume->V = (x2-x1)*(y2-y1)*(z2-z1);
}

void setInitialDomain(Domain (**p_domain)) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++) {
        (*p_domain)->x[i] = random_double();
        (*p_domain)->y[i] = random_double();
        (*p_domain)->z[i] = random_double();
    }
}

void setRandomDomain(Domain (*p_domain), Domain (**p_new_domain), Volume (*p_volume)) { 
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++) {
        (*p_new_domain)->x[i] = p_domain->x[i]*(double)(p_volume->upper_x - p_volume->lower_x) + (double)p_volume->lower_x;
        (*p_new_domain)->y[i] = p_domain->y[i]*(double)(p_volume->upper_y - p_volume->lower_y) + (double)p_volume->lower_y;
        (*p_new_domain)->z[i] = p_domain->z[i]*(double)(p_volume->upper_z - p_volume->lower_z) + (double)p_volume->lower_z;
    }
}

double setIntegrand(Domain (*p_domain), char c) {
    double *p_x = p_domain->x;
    double *p_y = p_domain->y;
    double *p_z = p_domain->z;
    if(c=='x')
        return *p_x;
    else if(c=='y')
        return *p_y;
    else if(c=='z')
        return *p_z;
    else
        return 1.;
}

double calculateIntegral(Domain (*p_domain), Volume (*p_volume), char c) {
    int i;
    double F = 0.;
    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++) {
        if(G(p_domain->x[i], p_domain->y[i], p_domain->z[i], p_volume->R)<=(double)p_volume->r) {
            F += setIntegrand(p_domain, c);
        }
    }
    return F*(double)p_volume->V/(double)DIM;
}

int main() {
    Domain *p_initial_domain;
    Domain *p_random_domain;

    constructDomain(&p_initial_domain);
    printf("Point 1: successful\n");
    constructDomain(&p_random_domain);
    printf("Point 2: successful\n");

    setInitialDomain(&p_initial_domain);

    Volume circle, *p_circle;
    p_circle = &circle;
    setVolume(p_circle,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0);
    setRandomDomain(p_initial_domain, &p_random_domain, p_circle);

    printf("PI/4 is approximately %f\n", calculateIntegral(p_random_domain, p_circle, 'p'));

    Volume torus, *p_torus;
    p_torus = &torus;
    setVolume(p_torus,3,1,1,4,-3,4,-1,1);
    setRandomDomain(p_initial_domain, &p_random_domain, p_torus);

    double M = calculateIntegral(p_random_domain, p_torus, 'p');
    double X = calculateIntegral(p_random_domain, p_torus, 'x');
    double Y = calculateIntegral(p_random_domain, p_torus, 'y');
    double Z = calculateIntegral(p_random_domain, p_torus, 'z');
    printf("rho integral is approximately %f\n", M);
    printf("x integral is approximately %f\n", X);
    printf("y integral is approximately %f\n", Y);
    printf("z integral is approximately %f\n", Z);
    printf("Centre of mass is approximately (%f, %f, %f)\n", X/M, Y/M, Z/M);

    delDomain(&p_initial_domain);
    delDomain(&p_random_domain);

// return pointers??
// array of structs??

    return 0;
}
```

Currently outputs:

```
PI/4 is approximately 0.785436
rho integral is approximately 22.101282
x integral is approximately 22.101801
y integral is approximately -45.953770
z integral is approximately 11.298411
Centre of mass is approximately (1.000023, -2.079235, 0.511211)
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Also, please can someone explain how I would use functions returning pointers and why it may be better to create an array of structs instead of a struct of arrays?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you call `setIntegrand` in a loop over all points, but you always take the first point:

```
double *p_x = p_domain->x;

// ...
return *p_x;
```

This returns the first `double` in your array. Remember that `*x` is equivalent to `x[0]`. Pass the index to the function:

```
double setIntegrand(Domain (*p_domain), char c, int i)
{
    if (c == 'x') return p_domain->x[i];
    if (c == 'y') return p_domain->y[i];
    if (c == 'z') return p_domain->z[i];
    return 1.;
}
```

and then call it with that index.

```
for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
    if (G(...) <= p_volume->r) {
        F += setIntegrand(p_domain, c, i);
    }
}
```

As to your additional questions: Using an array of structs keeps the things that go together (here, the three coordinates of the points) nearby. You can also easily just pass a point to a function with a single argument.

If you have a constructor, that is a function that creates a new thing by allocating on the heap and initialising the new memory, returning a pointer is a useful idiom. (I find it more idiomatic than passing a point to a pointer, but whoever designed to `fopen_s` function didn't think so.)

Let's put both changes together:

```
typedef struct Point Point;
typedef struct Domain Domain;

struct Point {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

struct Domain {
    size_t length;
    Point *point;
};

Domain *constructDomain(size_t length)
{
    Domain *dom = malloc(sizeof(*dom));

    if (dom) {
        dom->length = length;
        dom->point = calloc(length, sizeof(*dom->point));

        // check success
    }

    return dom;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First note, when possible it generally best to reduce the number of heap allocations and leave variables on the stack, less room for error. I'd say if you want `1M x 3 x sizeof(double)` bytes, arround 24M, it is best to dynamically allocate it on the heap. We can leave the structure that holds these on the stack.

Another thing is when you create a variable, you don't need to create another variable to point to it, just use the original variable.

Last note is commenting, I personally comment every line of code but that may be to much here. I find it helpful to write out what exactly you are trying to do with each line of code to help find bugs.

You don't need to return pointers anywhere here i don't think, perhaps when you were passing pointer to a pointer it would have been better to just return a pointer. An array of structures is another way of doing it, it means only one malloc and one free but alignment could cause extra memory to be used (padding) which could be considerable when using 1M points, there likely won't be any padding here tho because you are using double floating points. I think your arrays are fine.

I made some changes with the way you are using pointers, this likely won't solve your problem but it at least cleans things up a bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DIM 1000000

typedef struct Domain_t {
    double *x;
    double *y;
    double *z;
} Domain;

typedef struct Volume_t {
    int R;
    int r;
    int lower_x;
    int upper_x;
    int lower_y;
    int upper_y;
    int lower_z;
    int upper_z;
    int V;
} Volume;


double random_double() {
    static const int a = 16807;
    static const int c = 0;
    static const long long m = 2147483647;
    static long long seed = 1;
    seed = (a * seed + c) % m;
    return ((double) seed) / m;
}


void constructDomain(Domain *p_domain) {

    p_domain->x = malloc(DIM * sizeof(double));
    if (p_domain->x == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Memory allocation failed\n");
    }

    p_domain->y = malloc(DIM * sizeof(double));
    if (p_domain->y == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Memory allocation failed\n");
    }

    p_domain->z = malloc(DIM * sizeof(double));
    if(p_domain->z == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Memory allocation failed\n");
    }
}

void delDomain (Domain *p_domain) {
    if (p_domain != NULL) {
        free (p_domain->z);
        free (p_domain->y);
        free (p_domain->x);
    }
}

double radiusFunc(double point_x, double point_y) {
    return sqrt(pow(point_x,2)+pow(point_y,2));
}

double G(double point_x, double point_y, double point_z, int R) {
    return pow(point_z,2)+pow(radiusFunc(point_x,point_y)-(double)R,2);
}


void setVolume(Volume *p_volume, int R, int r, int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2, int z1, int z2) {
    p_volume->R = R;
    p_volume->r = r;
    p_volume->lower_x = x1;
    p_volume->upper_x = x2;
    p_volume->lower_y = y1;
    p_volume->upper_y = y2;
    p_volume->lower_z = z1;
    p_volume->upper_z = z2;
    if(z1 == 0 && z2 == 0)
        p_volume->V = (x2-x1)*(y2-y1);
    else if(y1 == 0 && y2 == 0)
        p_volume->V = (x2-x1)*(z2-z1);
    else if(x1 == 0 && x2 == 0)
        p_volume->V = (y2-y1)*(z2-z1);
    else
        p_volume->V = (x2-x1)*(y2-y1)*(z2-z1);
}

void setInitialDomain(Domain *p_domain) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++) {
        p_domain->x[i] = random_double();
        p_domain->y[i] = random_double();
        p_domain->z[i] = random_double();
    }
}

void setRandomDomain(Domain *p_domain, Domain *p_new_domain, Volume *p_volume) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++) {
        p_new_domain->x[i] = p_domain->x[i] * (double) (p_volume->upper_x - p_volume->lower_x) + (double) p_volume->lower_x;
        p_new_domain->y[i] = p_domain->y[i] * (double) (p_volume->upper_y - p_volume->lower_y) + (double) p_volume->lower_y;
        p_new_domain->z[i] = p_domain->z[i] * (double) (p_volume->upper_z - p_volume->lower_z) + (double) p_volume->lower_z;
    }
}

double setIntegrand(Domain (*p_domain), char c) {
    double *p_x = p_domain->x;
    double *p_y = p_domain->y;
    double *p_z = p_domain->z;
    if(c=='x')
        return *p_x;
    else if(c=='y')
        return *p_y;
    else if(c=='z')
        return *p_z;
    else
        return 1.0;
}

double calculateIntegral(Domain *p_domain, Volume *p_volume, char c) {
    int i;
    double F = 0.0;
    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++) {
        if(G(p_domain->x[i], p_domain->y[i], p_domain->z[i], p_volume->R)<=(double)p_volume->r) {
            F += setIntegrand(p_domain, c);
        }
    }
    return F * (double) p_volume->V / (double)DIM;
}

int main() {
    Domain initial_domain;
    Domain random_domain;
    Volume circle;
    Volume torus;

    /* memory allocation */
    constructDomain(&initial_domain);
    constructDomain(&random_domain);

    /* initialization */
    setInitialDomain(&initial_domain);

    /* volume */
    setVolume(&circle,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0);
    setRandomDomain(&initial_domain, &random_domain, &circle);

    /* integral */
    printf("PI/4 is approximately %f\n", calculateIntegral(&random_domain, &circle, 'p'));


    setVolume(&torus,3,1,1,4,-3,4,-1,1);
    setRandomDomain(&initial_domain, &random_domain, &torus);

    double M = calculateIntegral(&random_domain, &torus, 'p');
    double X = calculateIntegral(&random_domain, &torus, 'x');
    double Y = calculateIntegral(&random_domain, &torus, 'y');
    double Z = calculateIntegral(&random_domain, &torus, 'z');

    printf("rho integral is approximately %f\n", M);
    printf("x integral is approximately %f\n", X);
    printf("y integral is approximately %f\n", Y);
    printf("z integral is approximately %f\n", Z);
    printf("Centre of mass is approximately (%f, %f, %f)\n", X/M, Y/M, Z/M);

    delDomain(&initial_domain);
    delDomain(&random_domain);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have solved the original issue now but please could you explain alignment and padding?

Comment: Padding won't be an issue for this because you are using double floating point values but i'll explain. If you have a structure with say 3 characters in it (24 bits total). There will likely be some padding to align the data to 32-bits depending on the machine. so your 24-bit structure could take up 32 bits in memory, create a 1M array of these and you have lots of wasted memory due to alignment and padding. If you had arrays of characters, there is no need to pad or align. In your case you are using double floating point values each taking up 64-bits (depending on your machine), no padding

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Why is there no need to pad or align arrays of characters?

Comment: Because the array is a contiguous block of memory representing characters, one unit of memory, it might need some padding at the end of the array to make sure it is aligned properly. In the case of structures each structure is represented by a unit of memory that should be aligned. Does that make sense?